# Web Service dying after an hour

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-6

Recently we have upgraded our main product to be an ASP.NET 4.0 Project (upgraded from 2.0). This project is the main source of traffic to the web service, the other forms have not changed in this release. The web service has been running without issue for a couple years now.

Following the release of the 4.0 environment to our main product our web service starting to die after about an hour and would do nothing but timeout until we restarted the worker process.

We have changed it so that the web service was also in the 4.0 Framework. However this did nothing. Other possible attempts we have tried have also failed such as making it a service instead of a web reference, and updating our certificate validation to also use the proper/current framework techniques.

The worst part is that there is no log in the event viewer being created so I have no leads as to what the problem is. We have applied a band-aid solution of recycling the app pool every 20 min (the recompile takes a second as the web service is very small) and it seems to be holding for now, but we would rather fix the problem than rely on this. 
So does anyone have any additional idea/suggestions as to where our problem may be coming from? Or anyone experience anything similar?

Both projects exist in the same web farm and all machines are using IIS 6 32 bit.

Thanks!

edit- Some more info, The web service has a couple basic functions:

1 - accepts XML documents loads them into a dataset then updates internal DBs with the information sent - and simply returns true

2 - receives a request for processed data through XML and queries the DB for it builds XML response and sents it out

3 - receives a confirmation that the data requested in step 2 was recieved and deletes it from the DB

4 - hits a function that updates a DB so we can monitor some applications on our clients systems.

Comment: Unlike the answer suggesting using Process Explorer, I'd suggest running Process Monitor when it stops working. You can limit it only to watch the relevant processes. Process Monitor will maybe allow you to see what makes the Service die. Process Explorer will probably only let you see that it died.

Comment: I'm been abusing the WS all day and it seems like it is not clearing up any memory or resources the initial memory starts at about 25MB and is currently @ 53MB. I got it to slow down from being an instant call back to about 3-5 seconds, but then the number of handles went from 1200 to 900 and it was quick again. It seems like the WS is never cleaning itself up, and causing issues. Is there something I should do programmaticly in order to trigger this after the request is over? Or is there something else I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, can you reproduce the problem on a dev box (using some load testing platform to simulate production load)?

If so, then it sounds like an issue with your code. You could then take it a step further and profile the code on the dev server to pinpoint the issue.

If that isn't an option, I would fire up [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and watch the server resources over time. I'm not sure what your service does, but it sounds like it could be spinning up threads and then not cleaning up after itself.

It might help if you posted some sample code so we could see what could've been affected by the change from .NET 2.0 to 4.0.

Comment: If I remove the band-aid fix we have in place I can reproduce the issue internally on my dev box. We originally changed no code in accessing the service, now I have with some of the changes I mentioned. The thing is that it works fine until the process kills itself then it just stays dead. Up until then I can abuse it as much as I want. The service basically just takes user input from the webpage and returns SENT as an acknowledgement that it was transmitted successfully. So it is a very basic hit. I will check out the resources over time though.

Comment: @John - Then I would use a dev server and profile/monitor the service up until it dies. Without knowing more about what the service does, it's very difficult to make a more specific suggestion.

Comment: The service basically just takes user input from the webpage and returns SENT as an acknowledgement that it was transmitted successfully. So it is a very basic hit. - sorry i edited before because i hit enter accidentally :)